# how to extract string of letters and numbers greater than 4 characters long using regex?

Tags: regex

I want to extract the model number from the product name.
A model should be considered as a string of letters and numbers greater than 4 characters long.

For example in the following product name '26PFL3405H' is the model no.

*Philips 26PFL3405H Television*

By Model number I mean the word must contain atleast one number and one alphabet either in lower case or upper case

Comment: What have you tried so far? What flavor of regex? Where is the effort? By your definition of a model number, "Philips" and "Television" are also model numbers, but I doubt that's what you want. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an expression like this:

```
\b(?=[A-Z]+\d|\d+[A-Z])[A-Z\d]{4,}\b
```

To make it case insensitive use the `/i` flag or `(?i)`.

Comment: I should have specified this in the question. Modal must contain both numbers and letters but there is no condition of how much letter and how much number it contains. But in total modal name should be atleast 4 character long.

Comment: Thanks, Working good, but how can i modify it so that Model is atleast 4 character long?

Comment: @Ankit, forgot about that condition when editing. For that you are better off with a lookahead. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this regex :** (FIXED)

```
<?php

$product_name = "Philips 26PFL3405H Television";
$pattern = '/ (\w|\d[\d\w]+) /i';
preg_match($pattern, $product_name, $matches);

echo $matches[1];

?>

/\s([A-Z0-9]+)\s/
```

Comment: thanks, i am going to use this in php, your regex is not enforcing the model number to contain atleast one letter and 1 alphabet. Model must contain both letters and numbers.

Comment: @Ankit I've corrected it. It's now in PHP (+ enforcing AT LEAST one 1 letter and 1 word character matching)

Answer (score 1):

To meet the condition that it must contain both, the regular expression should look like,

```
[A-Z0-9]*(?:[A-Z][0-9]|[0-9][A-Z])[A-Z0-9]*
```

I am not entirely what is the best way to enforce the minimum length, but this would work,

```
(?:[A-Z][0-9]|[0-9][A-Z])[A-Z0-9]{3,}|[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z][0-9]|[0-9][A-Z])[A-Z0-9]{2,}|[A-Z0-9]{2,}(?:[A-Z][0-9]|[0-9][A-Z])[A-Z0-9]|[A-Z0-9]{3,}(?:[A-Z][0-9]|[0-9][A-Z])
```

Note that I have not posted a regular expression this long for something so seemingly simple without first giving it some thought; you may want to just filter the results of the first regular expression by length.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a 2-step approach: Filter size of 4+ first, and then look for alphabetic and numeric separately:

```
echo "12345 Philips 26PFL3405H Television" | egrep -o "\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,}\b" | egrep "[0-9]" | egrep "[a-zA-Z]" 
26PFL3405H
```